# Method injection into TestClass local namespace for automatic generation of Python unittest "test_xxx" methods

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, dynamic-loading

I am writing a series of unit tests in Python 3.5 `unittest`, which run the exact same test methods on different datasets.  The purpose is to validate proper behavior of each tested function over a range of inputs at different extremes of the likely numerical range of use (large values, small values, badly scaled values, etc.). I would like to construct the `TestCase` so that it dynamically generates all relevant `test_xxx` methods for the datasets I've entered.  This way it leaves me less room for typos, and avoids the need to write a raft of new functions every time I add a dataset.

I first wrote the test code with all of my dataset `dict` objects housed in a simple list, and a single `test_the_thing` function within my `unittest.TestCase` subclass.  `test_the_thing` would iterate over the list of `dict` datasets, running the test code on each. Two primary problems arose with this approach:

1. `unittest` considers the entire execution of `test_the_thing` to be a single test, and thus I have to search within my datasets to figure out which one failed when the test fails/errors.
2. When any given test fails/errors in the middle of the iteration, the remainder of the tests are not run.

What I've now got in its place is the following (the code for the entire class can be perused on [GitHub](https://github.com/bskinn/opan/blob/906d0f43295dc1b04f0a736de3e92bff9dfa15ee/opan/test/opan_utils_vector.py#L60-L363)):

```
class TestOpanUtilsVectorProjRejAngle(unittest.TestCase):
    import numpy as np
    from opan.const import OpanEnum

    class DType(OpanEnum):
        V1 = 'V1'
        V2 = 'V2'
        PROJ = 'PROJ'
        REJ = 'REJ'
        ANG = 'ANG'

    class VecType(OpanEnum): # Types of vectors
        O1 = 'O1'   # Both order-one
        LOL = 'LOL' # Both large (large on large)
        SOS = 'SOS' # Both small (small on small)
        LOS = 'LOS' # Large onto small
        SOL = 'SOL' # Small onto large
        BS = 'BS'   # Badly-scaled

    class RelType(OpanEnum): # Type of vector relationship
        NS = 'NS'      # Nonspecific
        PAR = 'PAR'    # Nearly parallel
        NORM = 'NORM'  # Nearly normal
        AP = 'AP'      # Nearly anti-parallel

    namestr = "{0}_{1}"

    # Dict of dicts of data
    data = {
            # Unremarkable vectors with ~order-one components
            namestr.format(RelType.NS, VecType.O1) :
                {DType.V1: np.array([1, 2, 3]),
                 DType.V2: np.array([-1, 3, 8]),
                 DType.PROJ: np.array([-0.391892, 1.175676, 3.135135]),
                 DType.REJ: np.array([1.391892, 0.824324, -0.135135]),
                 DType.ANG: np.float_(25.712002)},
            # ... more data sub-dictionaries are included
            }

    # Template functions
    # Vector projection template
    def template_proj(self, name, data):
        from opan.utils.vector import proj

        v1 = data[self.DType.V1]
        v2 = data[self.DType.V2]
        p = proj(v1, v2)
        for i, t in enumerate(zip(p, data[self.DType.PROJ])):
            self.assertAlmostEqual(*t, delta=1e-6,
                       msg="Test {0}: Index {1}; V1 = {2}; V2 = {3}"
                            .format(name, i, v1, v2))

    # Two more template functions ...

    # Populate the local namespace with the auto-generated 
    #  test methods
    for k, d in data.items():
        # Vector projection
        fxnname = "test_Vector_Proj_Good_{0}".format(k)
        fxn = lambda self, k=k, d=d: self.template_proj(k, d)
        locals().update({fxnname: fxn})

    # Populate for the other two template methods by the same approach ...
```

The test suite runs as expected: if I insert artificial errors in my 'known-good' values in `TestOpanUtilsVectorProjRejAngle.data`, the respective tests all fail as desired.

Some questions I have include:

- Is there a way to achieve this that is better/more secure than `locals().update(...)`?
- Is the lambda the best (or only?) way to encapsulate each function for packaging into the `TestOpanUtilsVectorProjRejAngle` local namespace?

General recommendations on making the code cleaner, more Pythonic, etc. are also appreciated.

Comment: Can you post your project on GitHub? I am interested in reading more of this.

Comment: I find this question very interesting but i also think it should be edited.

Comment: @Richard_Grant The project is already on GitHub: http://github.com/bskinn/opan.  This particular code is not yet committed to the project, however.  Once I get my current tests fully converted to this paradigm, I will be committing to the v.tests branch there.  I will think about how to edit my question to use the live code as cleanly as possible.

Comment: I had a feeling this was a much larger project. :) I will take some time and review the entire project (it might take some time).

Comment: @Richard_Grant You can find an alternative approach I used to streamline test population in [opan/opan/test/opan_utils_inertia.py](https://github.com/bskinn/opan/blob/master/opan/test/opan_utils_inertia.py), where I created a superclass inheriting from `object` that defines all of the `test_xxx` methods, and then subclasses that multiple-inherit from the superclass and from `unittest.TestCase` that are actually parsed and run by `unittest`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38872/discussion-between-brian-and-richard-grant).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your code is pretty good and you are following good practices with the exception to one (common mistake)

```
for name, datadict in data.items():
     fxnname = "test_data_{0}".format(name)
     fxn = lambda self, n=name, d=datadict: self.template_test_fxn(n, d)
     locals().update({fxnname: fxn})
```

Should be:

```
locals_ = locals()
for name, datadict in data.items():
     fxnname = "test_data_{0}".format(name)
     fxn = lambda self, n=name, d=datadict: self.template_test_fxn(n, d)
     locals_.update({fxnname: fxn})
```

This will prevent locals() from being evaluated when not necessary, but that's not even that big of a deal.

check out for another users use of locals https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028708/dynamically-set-local-variable-in-python

i encourage other developers to review this, as it is a very interesting project.